# MongoDB index creation in the background

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have seen in this question that creating index in the background does not release the Mongo shell:
[mongo createIndex background blocks the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042048/mongo-createindex-background-blocks-the-shell)

In that case, isn't there any ability to run the createIndex command linux-like in the background? (like &), I'm afraid that the index creation will take too long and due to network issues the SSH session will disconnect and then I'm not sure what will be the outcome.

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo createIndex background blocks the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042048/mongo-createindex-background-blocks-the-shell)

Comment: Documentation on [Index Build on Populated Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/index.html).